# Document database with custom inverted index... or Lucene + Solr?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, solr, lucene

Is there a database which allows me to create a custom inverted index? For my application, I have a lot of documents, and I need to allow the user to give the tags for the document, while also an automatic system is doing named entity recognition and adds more tags for the document. Now, I want to do the simplest search with those tags. That is, I give the database a set of tags and it returns the documents which is indexed with the highest number of those tags. I know Lucene is capable of doing this, but I feel is sort of an overkill, as its relevance function has a lot of other stuff in it (like the inverted document frecuency and other stuff), and its indexing function is too complicated. I was thinking of something like MongoDB, where I could insert a document, and then, in this custom index, I could add all the tags for the document. According to my research, it's not possible.

Do you know a database that allows this, or how to tune Lucene to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If this is just about tags, you can most probably do that with a standard relational database, many-to-many relationships (document -> mapping -> tags) and *group by*/*order by* queries. PostgreSQL, rather than MongoDB.

However, if you think your requirements will grow and they always do, you may benefit from using Solr. Then, you get faceting and full-text search and search across multiple fields for free.

Go with Solr rather than Lucene, as then you can use existing UpdateRequestProcessors and connect your Named Entity Recognition in there.